# Generating all possible permutations of the string

Tags: java, combinatorics

This generates all possible permutations of the string.  I am also unable to understand the time complexity of this problem. Can someone please explain the complexity to me?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class permutations {

    public ArrayList<String> performPermutations(String s){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }

        else if (s.length() == 0) {
            arrayList.add("");
            return arrayList;
        }

        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> remaining = performPermutations(s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1));
                for (int j = 0; j < remaining.size(); j++) {
                    arrayList.add(s.charAt(i) + remaining.get(j));
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permutations p = new permutations();
        ArrayList<String> arr = p.performPermutations("abcde");
            for(int i = 0; i<arr.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(arr.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can review your code (if it all works), but not explain the complexity, as we do not assist in explaining code given in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, Add an expected input/output along with some more explanation of exactly what your code does. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few ways this code can be improved:

- All class names should start with a capital, and be in CamelCase. Specifically, the class `permutations` should be `Permutations`. The way it doesn't look like a variable, as in here:

  ```
  permutations p = new permutations();
  ```

**performPermutations method**

- Why does it declare a return type of `ArrayList<String>`? Is there anything special about the implementation of the list? It should just be `List<String>`.
- You have an unnecessary `if-else` structure, since each `if` statement returns a value. You can remove all of the `else`s.
- In the first `if` statement, you return `null`. This is a bad idea in many cases. An empty list would be more favorable, just in case any calling code wants to operate on it immediately afterwards. (Notice that your `main` method would fail with a `NullPointerException` if the passed in list was empty).
- You can combine the first and second `if` statements into one. This would be your "base" case:

  ```
  if (s == null || s.isEmpty() { return arrayList; }
  ```

  Never compare a list length to 0, use `isEmpty()` instead. Also, `s` is a poor name for a method parameter. Try to be creative and descriptive. Finally, there's no need to add an empty string if the list is empty.
- [There's a lot of existing posts on string permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string) you may find interesting. Seeing a recursive call embedded in two `for` loops is probably unnecessarily complex.

How this method could look (but can still be improved):

```
public List<String> performPermutations(final String s){

    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (s == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        final List<String> remaining = performPermutations(s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < remaining.size(); j++) {
            result.add(s.charAt(i) + remaining.get(j));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe there's a bug at the if (s == null || s.isEmpty()). By removing the result.add(""), you're returning an empty list up to the parent recursive steps, which will ultimately cause an empty list to be returned overall.

Comment: Hmm maybe the page isn't refreshing correctly, but I don't think making the string and the list "final" and removing the isEmpty condition would fix the issue

Comment: Please feel free to edit or post a new answer which I'll upvote. It's too late for me to reexamine this answer.